# how do you loop thru a listbox and edit each line item in VB express 2010

Tags: loops, listbox

I have been learning VB for 4 weeks now and I have hit the limits of my knowledge. I sure could use some help from the more experienced programmers!!

Im trying to loop thru my list box and remove the first 4 chars of each line item.

specifically I would like it to behave like this:

first line of list box is selected and sent to string (minus 1st 4 chars)
first line of list box is removed from list box
modified version of first line of list box is added to list box in same position as original

next line of list box is selected...etc....
repeat until entire list box has been modified

Here is a sample of how I'm trying to do this....it almost works :)

Dim test As String
        test = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(4)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(test)

can someone fill in the blanks for me?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, just to double check, you are looping through right?

Next, we can take a look at this line:

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) ListBox1.Items.Add(test)
```

If I understand this right, you're removing the item at a specific index, then you're adding the new string, test, back into the list. Looking at this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx, it seems that add will stick this item at the end of the listbox, but you're removing something at a specified index.

Therefore, you're not actually replacing what you probably think you're replacing. That's my best guess. For example, if you remove the 2nd element in your list, but you when you put test back into the list, it's being added onto the end. So something like [a,b,c,d] becomes [a,c,d,b]

Perhaps changing that to:

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex) ListBox1.Items.Insert(ListBox1.SelectedIndex, test)
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox items can be accessed and edited in this way..

```
   listBox1.BeginUpdate();
try {
  for(int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    // do with listBox1.Items[i]

  }
} finally {
  listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```